# Condition evaluation stored in a variable inside (if statement) gives correct results whereas direct evaluation in (assert) gives erroneous results

Tags: vhdl, vivado

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity EqTB is
end EqTB;

architecture Behavioral of EqTB is
    signal a_in, b_in: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
    signal y_in: STD_LOGIC;
    component EqCmp is 
        port(
            a, b: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
            y: out STD_LOGIC
        );
    end component;
begin
    DUT: EqCmp port map(a => a_in, b => b_in, y => y_in);
    process
    begin
        a_in <= b"00";
        b_in <= b"01";
        wait for 100 ns;
        a_in <= b"11";
        b_in <= b"11";
        wait for 100 ns;
        a_in <= b"00";
        b_in <= b"00";
        wait for 100 ns;
        a_in <= b"11";
        b_in <= b"00";
        wait for 100 ns;
    end process;
    
    process (all)
        variable EQ: BOOLEAN := false;
    begin
--        if (((a_in = b_in) = true)  and y_in ='1')
--        or (((a_in = b_in) = false) and y_in = '0') then
--            EQ := true;
--        end if;
        EQ := (((a_in = b_in) = true)  and y_in ='1')
           or (((a_in = b_in) = false) and y_in = '0');
        assert (EQ)
            report "Fault occurred. " & std_logic'image(y_in) & boolean'image(EQ)
            severity ERROR;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

The previous code is a Testbench for the following module:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
entity EqCmp is
    Port(
        a: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
        b: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
        y: out STD_LOGIC
    );
end EqCmp;

architecture Behavioral of EqCmp is    
begin
    y <= '1' when (a = b) else '0';    
end Behavioral;
```

The problem is in the Testbench, The commented code in the last `process` works fine, but when I assign the `EQ` directly in the outer body of the process without using an if statement, it gives the following *reports*.

```
Error: Fault occurred. 'U' false
Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Process: /EqTB/line__34 
Error: Fault occurred. '1' false
Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 1  Process: /EqTB/line__34  
Error: Fault occurred. '0' false
Time: 100 ns  Iteration: 1  Process: /EqTB/line__34
Error: Fault occurred. '1' false
Time: 300 ns  Iteration: 1  Process: /EqTB/line__34
Error: Fault occurred. '0' false
Time: 500 ns  Iteration: 1  Process: /EqTB/line__34
Error: Fault occurred. '1' false
Time: 700 ns  Iteration: 1  Process: /EqTB/line__34
Error: Fault occurred. '0' false
Time: 900 ns  Iteration: 1  Process: /EqTB/line__34
```

And this is the simulation results, which seem to be correct: [image]

I also noted that it only happens on the change edge of the output. Else if the output stayed high, for example, no error produced.

Comment: You have a model with default signal assignment delays. `y` depends on `a` and `b` while all three are evaluated in the asserting process. `y` will change in the following delta simulation cycle.  Can you figure out why [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIGpz.jpg) doesn't assert? Remove one of the `wait for 0 ns;` statements. Do you see why you get the first assertion but not the rest?